# How to show a gradient within a style guide?

Tags: page-layout, critique, tables, style-guide

I'm building a new style guide for a sub-section of my company. I have most things listed and am working on the section talking about branding colors. My problem is that I've followed this design style throughout the guide but am now stumped on how I can show a gradient & the values in the same style/format as I did with colors.

[image: My color section]

This is what I came up with, but I feel like there might be a better way to show these.

[image: My fade section]

If there are any layout experts who have worked on similar projects and could help explain what they did to show gradients within their style guides would really help me out!

Comment: Hi ether, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks! IMO, I think your rendition for styling a gradient in a branding guideline is clear and fits your style based on the first image.

Comment: Hi @AndrewH I was worried about that, I checked the help page and was asking it under the terms of **"Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:"** followed by the section of "invite sharing experiences over opinions". I can revise the wording so it's more clear, thanks!

Comment: I think your solution matches pretty well with the initial color implementation.

Answer (score 4):

They did a nice job with this solution I think: https://angel.co/projects/277264-zeguro-style-guide-brand-design

It's clean but gets the point across.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brian, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: I see your point as that link has now indeed rotted. Fortunately the screen shot still answers the question of how to show a gradient in a style guide.  It doesn't however address how to show the gradient numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried creating an Object Style? What ever the parameters of an object are Object Styles are the way I would go. Then I would export the Object Style for others to implement.

Comment: That's not what is being asked; the question is about the visual aspect of the object.